# Multi-file gist of Jupyter notebook and associated images?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, blogger, gist

I have a Jupyter document that displays 3 image files from the same directory. I want to publish it in blogger, and in the past have hosted a single, complete file as a gist then inserted it into blogger; but I can't seem to add more than one file to a github gist. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here it explains how to add more files into a gist: https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/feff40b0a522f0c41c4eff0b77ea1d47

Basically, you have to clone the gist repository add, commit, and push the files, and when you refresh your gist you should see more than one file there.